# Viewmodel set up Aspt.net MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm having trouble understanding how to implement a ViewModel in Asp.net MVC, I have the following tables:

### Form

ID, Data

### Report

ID, FormID, Owner, Category, Status, SubmissionDate

### ReportValues

ID, ReportID, Title, Value

I'm looking for a way to display and edit Report and ReportValues in the one ViewModel where ReportValues.ReportID = Report.ID

ReportValues will have multiple entries that relate to a Report.

I have had a look at similiar questions on here and tried following a tutorial ( http://techfunda.com/howto/262/list-data-using-viewmodel ) and coming up empty handed.

If you need any more information let me know and thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: can you post code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your View Model is nothing more than a class. You can solve this many ways, but here's an example.

Create your 3 classes like you normally would.

```
public class Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class ReportValues
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then, create your ViewModel class to include the three above classes like this.

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public Form Form { get; set; }
    public ReportValues ReportValues { get; set; }
    public Report Report { get; set; }
}
```

In your view you can access your three classes and their properties as you would in your controller. `Model.Form.Id`

Depending on your data types, `ReportValues` will likely be a property of `Report`, but that's entirely up to your data structure. You will need to populate the classes using whatever method you want (Entity Framework, ADO, etc.) before you can pass them to your view and use them.

Comment: For clarification, the first 3 classes are within the Models folder, should the ReportViewModel go inside this same folder or the ViewModels folder?

Comment: I wasn't aware of a Models AND ViewModels folder. Your models and view models should all go into the Models folder. There is also a Views folder, but that holds all of your cshtml files. If you want to really separate your classes well, I'd suggest a Class Library project to store your Form, Report, and ReportValues classes that your MVC project references. Also, your data access would happen in another class library.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of VS, Asp.net and MVC and it has a ViewModels folder, I will go with placing the 4th class in the Models folder for now. Thanks

Comment: I guess I should get rid of my old VS 2013 and hop on board the 2016 train. Thanks for the info. I'll be on the lookout for the extra folders.